# Bypass server killing php script

Tags: php, cron, fopen

I'm trying to create a cronjob in php by using a script with `ignore_user_abort(true);` and `set_time_limit(0);`. The basic works, but unfortunately the process is killed anyway after 15mins by the server.

Now i'm using `fopen` to bypass this by requesting the page again before its killed. This works as expected the first time (it truncates the table, loops and then loads page with id=2). A second row with id=2 is inserted and the loop starts correct. Unfortunately after page 2 it keeps using the same Id, it does not continue with id=3, 4, etc.

Anybody has an idea on how to fix this?

Sample code i use for testing:

```
<?php
ignore_user_abort(true);
set_time_limit(0);
$interval=1;
$startTime = time();
$maxLoop = 10;
$id = (strlen($_GET['id'])>0) ? trim($_GET['id']) : 1;


require_once('ct2database.php');
ct2database::init();

if ($id==1) {
  //init table
  ct2database::query("TRUNCATE TABLE crontest");
}
ct2database::query("INSERT INTO crontest (Id, Counter, StartDate) VALUES (".$id.", 0, '".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."')");

//loop
do{
  ct2database::query("UPDATE crontest SET Counter=Counter+1 WHERE id=".$id);
  sleep($interval);
}while($maxLoop--);


$newid = $id+1;
$url = 'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].'?id='.$newid . '&t='.time();

//regular end of loop
ct2database::query("UPDATE crontest SET EndDateRegular='".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."' WHERE id=".$id);

$context = stream_context_create( array(
  'http'=>array(
    'timeout' => 0.5
  )
));
$fp = fopen($url, 'r', false, $context);


register_shutdown_function('ShutdownHandler');
function ShutdownHandler() {
  global $id;
  //update on shutdown
  ct2database::query("UPDATE crontest SET EndDateShutdown='".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."' WHERE id=".$id);
}

set_error_handler("ErrorHandler"); 
function ErrorHandler() {
  global $id;
  //update on error
  ct2database::query("UPDATE crontest SET EndDateError='".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."' WHERE id=".$id);
}

?>
```

and a result:

```
Array
(
    [Id] => 1
    [Counter] => 10
    [DateModified] => 2012-12-21 16:01:54
    [StartDate] => 2012-12-21 16:01:42
    [EndDateRegular] => 2012-12-21 16:01:53
    [EndDateShutdown] => 2012-12-21 16:01:54
    [EndDateError] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
)
Array
(
    [Id] => 2
    [Counter] => 55
    [DateModified] => 2012-12-21 16:02:49
    [StartDate] => 2012-12-21 16:01:54
    [EndDateRegular] => 2012-12-21 16:02:49
    [EndDateShutdown] => 2012-12-21 16:02:49
    [EndDateError] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
)
```

Comment: What it's killed by? Does PHP spit out any errors?

Comment: What are the values of `max_execution_time` and `safe_mode`?

Comment: I dont see anything because I already closed the browser. If I run it in an eternal loop it will end after 15mins and not even the shutdown trigger is called

Comment: i'm setting the max_execution_time with set_time_limit to 0 and I can keep the script running for 15mins. In the current scenario it only runs for 10*1 second so its not the max_execution time. Also it keeps updating the counter, so it keeps running. It just keeps running on ID=2 after id 1 is done. Also running 5.4+ so no safe_mode

Comment: From the manual [set_time_limit](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php): "This function has no effect when PHP is running in safe mode."

Comment: PHP in CLI mode (e.g. a cron job) should NOT have a time limit anyways. That's usually only applied when running within a webserver. Exactly how is your cron job invoking this script? `wget http://yourserver.com/job.php` as an http request? direct command line `/usr/bin/php /path/to/your/job.php`?

Comment: Ok I should have been more clear. I'm simulating a cronjob with a php script. This scripts should just keer running in the background forever (or server restart) and perfom some operation in the loop. @Olaf > 5.4+ has no safe_mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your script "restart" with this small example and it worked fine so far.

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $id = $_GET['id'];
} else {
    $id = 1;
}

echo "$id ";
++$id;
$url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?id=' . $id;

if ($id < 10) {
    $fp = fopen($url, 'r');
    $buf = fread($fp, 100);
    echo $buf;
    fclose($fp);
}
```

However, I used `PHP_SELF`, because `REQUEST_URI` includes the complete path including parameter `id`. This builds up to urls like `http://server/path?id=1?id=2?id=3?id=...`. I also read the output from the script, otherwise it might block, when some output occurs.

Another point to keep in mind is, that this is effectively an endless recursion. This might result in `connection refused` errors at some time.

So the real solution should be to look into the server logs and find out, what's real reason for your problem.

Comment: You are right. stupid mistake not using php_self. Nice catch. connection refused isnt an issue as it each script ends after 10seconds but starts a new hidden process.